# mod_security log reports missing User-Agent and blocks Ajax Request 403 , but User-Agent is present

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, user-agent, mod-security

From Log I am getting **Error**:

> ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). 
>   Operator EQ matched 0 at REQUEST_HEADERS. 
>   [msg "Request Missing a User Agent Header"] [severity "NOTICE"] 
>   [tag "OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/MISSING_HEADER_UA"]

But when I check in Network > XHR tab the header is present:

> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36

I use standard AngularJS:

```
const ajax = function(data, url, completeFn, errorFn){
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data:data,
  headers:{
    'Accept': "application/json",
    'Content-Type': "application/json"
  }
})
.then( completeFn, errorFn );}
```

Later called by

```
this.select_all = function( callback ){
 ajax({action: 'select_all'}, url, 
    function(response){
      self.allFolders = response.data;
      if(callback){ callback(response); }
    }, 
    defError
 );}
```

I am using mod_rewrite rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  Options FollowSymLinks
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /webpage/#/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

When I completely disable mod_security everything works as it should. But I am not sure I want to do that. I googled for 2 hours couldn't find anything about similar issue. I must be doing something wrong. How should be this done?

Comment: Is the header in the audit log? Can you also give the rule config? It seems to be checking for any request header based on the log extract you have given.

Comment: I have only HTTP access log, from which I posted error and there is no header there. I am not sure If they are supposed to be visible there. I have very limited access to server settings. Just few options. Error looks as mentioned that there is no header at all...meanwhile in chrome I can see all headers in request.

I think all I can do is to write something to .htaccess file without knowing current settings.

Comment: Going to be really difficult to Debug without that. Suggest you ask for help from someone with that access. I honestly doubt above error message is to do with your request btw - suspect your request is being blocked by another rule unrelated to the missing UA rule.

Comment: Yes, it seems like that. Because I wasn't able to find any mention of similar issue to this one on internet. I must be searching for problem in wrong place. Thanks for your reply :)